# How to create new entity with default value in Vuex-ORM

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-orm

How can I create a new entity that does not persist in vuex from a vuex-orm model class with default values that's not created in the vuex "database"?

Comment: Do you mean how to instantiate a model with default values?

Comment: Nope. How to instantiate a model that doesn't persist in vuex. I clarified the question.

Comment: Models are just javascript objects. So `new User({ attributes })` is all you need.

Comment: That's it! Thanks, @Cue!